# Spread attribute and recursively join in standalone pyqgis app

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins, splitting, standalone

**TL;DR**

Is there a pyqgis equivalent to R's `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::cast` ? If not, how do we recursively join by attribute n layers to another without erasing previous join ?

### The problem

I have a layer that contains qualitative data in a given field.
I'm trying to programmatically separate the modalities of this field and then join them to a grid layer in distinct columns.

Basically, what I'm trying to do resembles functions such as `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::cast` for those familiar to data wrangling with R. Only I'm trying to do this in a standalone pyqgis application.

### Sample

The is meant to work with any given ogr vector that has areal qualitative data. Therefore, the program must loop to get each modalities in a given `data` field

**Data table (data.shp) after intersection with grid**

`id | data | area
 1 | cat1 | 123
 1 | cat. | 456
 1 | catn | Null
.. | cat1 | 012
.. | cat. | 345
.. | catn | 678
 n | cat1 | 890
 n | cat. | 123
 n | catn | 456`

**Expected result**

`id | cat1  | cat. | catn
 1 | 123   | 456  | 789
.. | 012   | 345  | 678
 n | Null  | 123  | 456`

### My almost but not quite working solution

The best I can come up with is this :

1. Get feature and append to a list with `data.getFeatures()`
2. Split data layer with `processing.runalg("qgis:splitvectorlayer")`
   This creates n shapefiles in a temporary folder that I destroy at the end of the program.
3. In a `for` loop on point 1. list, load/Edit the splitted files by reconstructing the path with `.format`, storing each `QgsVectorLayer()` in another list and finally editing the field name with `lyr.startEditing()` `lyr.renameAttribute()` and `lyr.commitChanges()`

This all works fine.

4. Final step is to recursively join splitted layers onto the grid layer. The following doesn't work :
   In a `for` loop on point 3. list (modalLyr), I reconstruct the field name and attempt an `addJoin()`, like this :

```

```
for lyr in modalLyr:
areaField = "sup_{}".format(modalLyr.index(lyr))

joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = lyr.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = "id"
joinObject.targetFieldName = "id"
joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset([areaField])
joinObject.memoryCache = True
grid.addJoin(joinObject)
```

```

The problem with this is that I only get one additional field in my output, instead of n areaFields...

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Lecram! If you use `print areaField` inside your `for` loop, are the field names correct for each `lyr`?

Comment: @Joseph : Thanks for the welcome and also for your many contributions that have often been very helpful. If I print the following in my loop : `
    areaField = "sup_{}".format(modalLyr.index(lyr))
    fields = [field.name() for field in lyr.pendingFields() ]
    print "Layer fields : {}\n Reconstructed field name : {}\n".format(fields, areaField`, well I get the confirmation the reconstructed field name is correct. For the first in my test data : 
 Layer fields : [u'id', u'area', u'Contour', u'zone', u'sup_0']
 Reconstructed field name : sup_0

Answer (score 1):

I managed to hack my way into a solution using the processing algorithm rather than `addJoin`, and using a memory layer (`None` in `OUTPUT_LAYER`) to store iterations that were otherwise getting erased at each loop. It goes as follows :

```
for lyr in modalLyr:
    joinAlg = processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributestable",
                    {"INPUT_LAYER": grid,
                    "INPUT_LAYER_2": lyr,
                    "TABLE_FIELD": "id",
                    "TABLE_FIELD_2": "id",
                    "OUTPUT_LAYER": None})
    joinMemo = joinAlg["OUTPUT_LAYER"]
joinLyr = QgsVectorLayer(joinMemo, "joinLyr", "ogr")
```

It works, but there could be a better solution, i.e. one that doesn't leave a mess of redundant fields to clear up and one that does not use memory layers (as the standalone in meant to be on a server that never reboots, each execution will be wasting memory space...)